# How to make a space between icon and text in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am learning HTML and CSS. I am practicing by designing some pages but I got a problem. I tried many ways but couldn't fix it. I want to add a space between the icon and the text so that they lock more beautiful.

**Image**:

[image]

**CSS**:

```
.facebook {
    background: blue;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    padding-left: 4.1vw;
    padding-right: 4.1vw;
    margin-left: 0vw;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.facebook:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.google {
    background: red;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    padding-left: 4.6vw;
    padding-right: 4.6vw;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.google:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="login-with">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook">Facebook</i></a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="google"> <i class="fab fa-google">Google</i> </a>
        </div>
```

Can you please help me to fix it. When I add a space manually the link text go to below the icon.

Full Codes link:

CSS: [Full Code](https://codeshare.io/G8bO1B)

HTML: [Full Code](https://codeshare.io/arZQ8A)

Comment: make the text outside the `i`

Comment: I guess your icon is in the `before` pseudo element - you could try `.fab:before {margin-right:1em}`, otherwise as temani says, move your text outside the i and add margin to that

Comment: In your CSS try something like `.fab::before { content:" "}`

Comment: Thank you so much all of you. I got the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try one of the below methods as mentioned in Fontawesome [examples page](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/)

Text outside `i` tag, and add a space in between

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
```

Use `&nbsp;`, below code is from Fontawesome site

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
```

If you dont want to change your markup(html) use the below CSS

```
.login-with > a i::before {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: @DabanandaMitra I have also added a CSS method if you dont want to change your html

Comment: You are so much helpful sir. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

People usually keep the icon element as an empty node and put the text content after it. Then you add a margin to the icon to get appropriate spacing:

```
.facebook .fab { margin-right: 1em }

<a href="..." class="facebook">
   <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
   <span>Facebook</span>
</a>
```

The `<span>` tags are technically not necessary, but it is common to avoid text-only nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use **space** or **&nbsp** between text and icon. Also plz put **;**  after **&nbsp**

Comment: Life saver.
Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Place service name outside `i` tag.
You can add `margin-right: 10px;` styling to `i` element,
or `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` to the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to set a base class for the social icons

```css
/* set base class */
.social-btn {
  padding: 0.8rem 4.1vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* space the buttons */
.social-btn + .social-btn {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

/* set icon padding */
.social-btn i {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

/* Modifiers */
.facebook-btn {
  background: blue;
}

.google-btn {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="social-btn facebook-btn"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>

<a href="#" class="social-btn google-btn"><i class="fab fa-google"></i>Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Bootstrap` you can use `me` which represents **margin from end** in **icon**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 style="width:150px;"><i class="bi bi-info-circle me-2"></i>Information</button>
```

### Sample Code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;"><i class="bi bi-info-circle me-2"></i>Information</button>
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px;"><i class="bi bi-gear-fill me-3"></i>Settings</button>
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:150px;"><i class="bi bi-person-circle me-3"></i>Profile</button>
    </center>
    
  </body>
</html>
```